# EF6 with IQueryable doesn't bring in navigation property when querying many-side

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF6 in a code-first model and I'm having problems bringing in an eager-loaded, navigation property when I'm querying the 'many' side of a one-to-many relation.  I've tried adding an .Include to the .Where but it throws an error.

```
public partial class OneSide
{
    public OneSide()
    {
      Configurations = new Collection<ManySide>();
    }
    ...
    // navigation properties
    public ICollection<ManySide> Configurations { get; set; }
}


public partial class ManySide
{
    ...
    public int IND2OBJECT { get; set; }
    // navigation properties
    public OneSide Listing { get; set; }
}
```

In OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ManySide>()
            .HasRequired<OneSide>(s => s.Listing)
            .WithMany(s => s.Configurations).HasForeignKey(s => s.IND2OBJECT);
```

This is what I'm doing to query it - thinking I add the .Include after the .Where:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

IQueryable<ManySide> allRecs = DbContext.ManySides;

IQueryable<ManySide> dayRecs =
                allRecs.Where(
                    x => (string.Compare("2014", x.begin) >= 0) && 
                    (string.Compare("2015", x.end) <= 0)).Include( b => b.Listing);

foreach (var dayRec in dayRecs)  // <-- error happens here
  <do something with dayRec>
```

The error I get is:

```
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ManySide' does not 
declare a navigation property with the name 'Listing'.
```

But I have a navigation property defined in the POCO and in the OnModelCreating I have the one-to-many relation defined correctly in the Fluent API, do I not?  I also tried not using the DBExtentions (with .Include("Listing") ), but same result.

If I remove .Include completely, I get ManySide records ok, but 'Listing' is null.

Thanks for any advice!
Corey.

Comment: both properties should be virtual `public virtual OneSide Listing { get; set; }`

Comment: ...even if I want eager loading?